# How to make a proper mask for PIL's paste method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I can't understand why I can't mask an image with the mask I made :

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg") 
mask_card = Image.open("images/mask_card.png").convert("RGBA")


essai = Image.new('RGBA', (img.width,img.height))
essai.paste(img,(0 , 0),mask_card)
essai.show()
```

I then try to force the mask to be only black and white, but it is not working better :

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg") 
mask_card = Image.open("images/mask_card.png").convert("RGBA")


datas = mask_card.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if (max(item[0], item[1], item[2]) > 100 ) :
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 255))
    else:
        newData.append((0, 0, 0, 255))
mask_card.putdata(newData)

mask_card.show()

essai = Image.new('RGBA', (img.width,img.height))
essai.paste(img,(0 , 0),mask_card)
essai.show()
```

With image.png being (I want to mask the white corners) :

[image]

and mask_card.png being :

[image]

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mask_image is rgba image that contain transparency channel so you've to make transparency = 0 for white pixel to be disappear when merging. Also, you are using paste method incorrectly. Instead of creating new image, paste mask into the image directly.
Technically, the mask parameter tells PIL where on the source image pixel value should be replace and where it shouldn't. So passing the mask_card into `paste` method won't merge the mask into the image.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open("image.jpg")
mask_card = Image.open("images/mask_card.png").convert("RGBA")
data = mask_card.getdata()
newData = []
for item in data:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

mask_card.putdata(newData)
img.paste(mask_card,(0,0),mask_card)
img.save('res.png')
```

res.png
[image]